# How can I make my toggle switches stay in their current positions when navigating to new pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, toggle

I have two toggle switches in my current project. One is for dark/light mode, and another shows/hides the menu on mobile.

I've noticed whenever the user refreshes the page, clicks the "back to top" arrow, or just navigates to a new page, they reset. This breaks the user experience, so I'd like to know how I can make them constantly stay on or off until the user clicks them again (or navigates away from the site).

Here is a video of it in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yk2A.jpg

Below is the code. What can I add or change?

```js
const body = document.getElementById('body');
const darkModeSwitch = document.getElementById('darkModeSwitch');
const menuSwitch = document.getElementById('onOffSwitch');
const mainNavItems = document.getElementById('mainNavItems');

//Show main menu when switch is clicked
menuSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (mainNavItems.style.display === 'block') {
        mainNavItems.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        mainNavItems.style.display = 'block';
    }
});

//Dark Mode
darkModeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let currentBodyClass = body.className;
        if (body.className === "lightMode") {
            body.className = "darkMode";
        } else if (currentBodyClass === "darkMode") {
            body.className = "lightMode";
        }
    
});
```

```css
#mainNav * {
        color: #FFF;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #mainNav {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #mainNavLogo {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 25px 0;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    #mainNavItems {
        display: none;
        width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    #mainNavItems div {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #mainNavItems h2:hover {
        color: #db7a3d !important;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    #onOffSwitch {
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 20px;
    }

    #darkModeSwitch {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
    }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #cecece;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: .25s;
}

input:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  background: #db7a3d;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: .35s;
}

input:checked[type="checkbox"]:before {
  top: 25px;
}

/* DARK MODE */
#darkModeSwitch  {
  background: #fff892;
}

#darkModeSwitch:checked {
  background: #757575;
}

#darkModeSwitch:before {
  background: #fff;
}

#darkModeSwitch:checked:before {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="lightMode">
        <div class="wrap">
            <header>
                <div id="mainNav">
                    <input id="darkModeSwitch" type="checkbox" title="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" aria-label="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
                    <input id="onOffSwitch" type="checkbox" title="Show/Hide Menu" aria-label="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
                    <div id="mainNavLogo"><a href="home.html"><h1>Worth it!?</h1></a></div>
                    <div id="mainNavItems">
                        <div><a href="about.html"><h2>About</h2></a></div>
                        <div><a href="contact.html"><h2>Contact the Developer</h2></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </header>
            
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could save the user preference for dark/light mode & hide/show menu using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). When the user visits the page, check for their preference so you don't keep overriding their preference.

```js
localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');
localStorage.getItem('mode');          // you get back dark
```

Comment: How exactly do I add this? Do I need to do an if/else statement or click event listener?

Comment: this video explains it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wodWDIdV9BY